Cookies Are Saved when sign up and sign in but not when updating
In Backend Node Express I can verifyUser by cookies but when i want to update user, the cookies are undefined ,
I also have used cookieParser and The cookie path is "/" .When i try it in Postman it works fine but cannot seem to update it the cookie console.log(above) returns undefined

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
